# php variable isn't updating

Tags: php, openweathermap

I'm new to php, and I have a problem. Through an exercise from my school, I have to create a little weather website using 2 API (and more). I'm using OpenWeatherMap, it's working but when I'm trying to put an icon in adequacy with what OpenWeatherAPI give me, my variables **$url_icon** and **$icon_weather** aren't updating

```
<div><i class="wi <?= $url_icon?>"></i></div>
<div><?= $icon_weather ?></div>
```

And my PHP

```
$icon_weather = $data_weather->weather[0]->icon; 
$url_icon = "wi-day-sunny";

if($icon_weather = '01d' || '01n'){
$url_icon = "wi-day-sunny";
} else if($icon_weather = '02d' || '02n'){
$url_icon = "wi-day-cloudy";
} else if($icon_weather = '03d' || '04n'){
$url_icon = "wi-cloud";
} else if($icon_weather = '04d' || '04n'){
$url_icon = "wi-cloudy";
} else if($icon_weather = '09d' || '09n'){
$url_icon = "wi-rain";
} else if($icon_weather = '10d' || '10n'){
$url_icon = "wi-day-rain";
} else if($icon_weather = '11d' || '11n'){
$url_icon = "wi-storm-showers";
} else if($icon_weather = '13d' || '13n'){
$url_icon = "wi-snow-wind";
};
```

The weirdest is that without my if loop (so without $url_icon too), icon_weather is updating well :(

Thanks !

Comment: do `var_dump($icon_weather = $data_weather->weather[0]->icon);`

Comment: comparing within control structures like if statements requires two = signs not one. If you use one = sign you are assigning instead of comparing.. i vote closing this question because it's a simple typographical error... Also a other hint indent your code for readability

Comment: Flagged as typo. If statement comparison should be `==`

Comment: try `$icon_weather == '02d' || $icon_weather == '02n'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should be the following

```
 $icon_weather = $data_weather->weather[0]->icon; 
 $url_icon = "wi-day-sunny";

 if($icon_weather == '01d' || $icon_weather == '01n'){
     $url_icon = "wi-day-sunny";
 } else if($icon_weather == '02d' || $icon_weather=='02n'){
     $url_icon = "wi-day-cloudy";
 } else if($icon_weather == '03d' || $icon_weather=='04n'){
     $url_icon = "wi-cloud";
 } else if($icon_weather == '04d' || $icon_weather=='04n'){
     $url_icon = "wi-cloudy";
 } else if($icon_weather == '09d' ||$icon_weather== '09n'){
     $url_icon = "wi-rain";
 } else if($icon_weather == '10d' || $icon_weather=='10n'){
     $url_icon = "wi-day-rain";
 } else if($icon_weather == '11d' || $icon_weather=='11n'){
     $url_icon = "wi-storm-showers";
 } else if($icon_weather == '13d' || $icon_weather=='13n'){
     $url_icon = "wi-snow-wind";
 };
```

To compare variables using if, you should use == and not =

Answer (score 0):

each of your if statements needs to have the double equal sign (==) to compare.

Your class text is already set to wi with a space and then its adding wi-day-thisval making it wi wi-day-thisval.

also you need to echo in order for it to display.

my personal opinion also is that

```
<div><i class="<?php echo $url_icon ?>"></i></div>
<div><?php echo $icon_weather ?></div>
```